# How to set event in tablecalendar with APi response?

Tags: flutter, events, calendar, dart-pub, table-calendar

i need to set event in calendar in flutter Application, and i am getting event data from API here is response,i will be very thankful for it , i am sharing my api response and what type of calendar i want to show

```
 "leave_management": [
            {
                "leave_date": "Jan 01, 1970",
                "holiday_type": "partialy_off",
                "holiday_reason": "urgent work at home"
            },
            {
                "leave_date": "Jan 01, 1970",
                "holiday_type": "partialy_off",
                "holiday_reason": "urgent work at home"
            }
        ]
```

[image]

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar

Comment: i have try so many times but i could not set it. could you please share a demo code.